# Cordova Run Android always result in Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova

I am still new with this cordova command line interface thing, and need help with this issue. I have removed and re-added android platform to my cordova project; I have also downgraded the android version in SDK manager to Android 5.0 (Lollipop).

Every Time I Run "Cordova Run Android", this happens:

[image: Every Time I Run "Cordova Run Android" this happen:]

The error occur after it said "BUILD SUCCESSFUL":

[image: The error occur after it said "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"]

I need to solve this soon because the deadline is near. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Screenshots should be for illustrative purposes only. Always include the code, command output or any other text in screenshots as text (formatted as code) in your question body.

Comment: Alright, I got the solution now, it's happen because I already have the installed cordova android app with previous version of cordova attached in my android device, when I erase that app in my android device and enter the "cordova run android" command, and now it works. 

@tambre Thanks for the input, will keep that in mind :)

Comment: If you found a solution, then you should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in my cable data, because sometimes this "cordova run android" command can succesfully launched to my android device and sometimes not, but it can be successful again if I adjust my android device cable data.